# Aplicação UWP executar sequencia de vídeos no MediaElement vindo de uma List<string>

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, iot

Estou usando o `Media Element` em uma aplicação `UWP` para rodar uma sequência de vídeos, como faço para quando um vídeo termine o outro rode em sequencia?

No código abaixo quando o primeiro vídeo da `List<string> videos10` acaba o outro da sequencia não roda

Minha ideia é fazer a função `SequenciaDeVideosNoArquivoTexto();` receber uma sequencia de nomes de vídeos vinda de um arquivo de texto.

Assim com o arquivo texto terei o total controle da sequencia de vídeos que irei trocar constantemente.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        SequenciaDeVideosNoArquivoTexto();
    }


    private void SequenciaDeVideosNoArquivoTexto()
    {
        //A LIST ABAIXO FAREI PEGAR AS INFORMAÇÕES DO ARQUIVO TEXTO
        List<string> videos10 = new List<string>();
        videos10.Add("Call Farma");
        videos10.Add("Dia Mundial");
        videos10.Add("Dolex Nueva");
        videos10.Add("Mori Farma");

        foreach (var item in videos10)
        {
            LoadMediaFromString("ms-appx:///Videos/" + item + ".mp4");
        }
    }


    private void LoadMediaFromString(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri pathUri = new Uri(path);
            mediaPlayer.Source = pathUri;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            if(ex is FormatException)
            {

            }

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar o objeto `MediaPlaybackList();`, adicionar seus videos à essa playlist e depois atribuí-la como source do seu player.

[Referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource)

Comment: você poderia me mostrar como usar o objeto MediaPlabackList(); como faço para adicionar os videos nesta Playlist.

Comment: Leandro Angelo vendo alguns exemplos na internet é explicado como pegar o arquivo desejado através - var filePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker(); mas no meu caso eu irei passar as informações através de um arquivo texto que terá os nomes dos vídeos, como fazer para ao invés de usar o FileOpenPicker eu passe estes nomes.